# Rational Inequality Question with cos and e

Tags: inequality

I'm not sure how to go about this problem as it is more complex than a typical rational inequality
Find the set $$\left\{x\in[-4,4]\biggr\rvert\frac{(x+1)cos(\pi x)}{e^x (x-2)}<0\right\}$$

Comment: There seems to be something missing... ordinarily you write a set in set-builder notation as $\{x\in A~|~P(x)\}$ where $P(x)$ is some logical statement which for each value of $x$ is either true or false.  What is on the right of your set builder notation is not a logical statement, but just an expression with no truth value associated to it whatsoever...

Comment: I guess OP means$$\left\{\frac{(x+1)cos(\pi x)}{e^x (x-2)} : x\in[-4,4]\right\}.$$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the < 0 part

Comment: In order for $f(x)/g(x) \lt 0$, it must be either that the numerator is positive and the denominator negative, or that the numerator is negative and the denominator positive.  Don't get too perplexed about cosine and exponential functions, because they don't really make this problem difficult.

Answer (score 1):

In
$\left\{x\in[-4,4]\biggr\rvert\frac{(x+1)cos(\pi x)}{e^x (x-2)}<0\right\}
$,
you have four subexpressions:
$(x+1),
cos(\pi x),
e^x ,
(x-2)
$.

For the indicated fraction
to be negative,
an odd number of them
must be negative
(do you see why?).

One of them is always positive
(do you see which one?),
so it does not affect the sign.

Your mission,
if you choose to accept it,
is to examine the other three expressions
in the specified interval
and decide where they are positive
or negative.

From this,
you can decide
where the compound expression
is negative.

Comment: I understand that an odd number need to be negative and I know $e^x$ is the one that is always positive but I am still unsure about solving it.

Comment: @randb:  I think you can solve what subset of $[-4,4]$ makes each of the three "doubtful" expressions $(x+1),(x-2), \cos \pi x$ positive (resp. negative).  Do each piece, then work out the number of these expressions that are negative in the corresponding intersections of subintervals.